# Flutter local_auth platform exception requires activity to be a fragmentactivity flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am using the plugin `local_auth` to let users authenticate by their fingerprint, now I know that there are some changes that need to be done on 'mainActivity.kt' so the plugin gets working without the error `local_auth plugin requires activity to be a fragmentactivity flutter`

but the problem is I am using google_ads plugin too and I am registering native ads with it that using the context inside the class FlutterActivity so I can't change it to FlutterFragmentActivity or I am getting `Unresolved reference: context`

```
package app.masarifi

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
//        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
//
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(
                flutterEngine, "listTile", ListTileNativeAdFactory(context))

        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(
                flutterEngine, "mediumAd", MediumNativeAdFactory(context))

    }

    override fun cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "listTile")
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "mediumAd")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:
**context** => **applicationContext**.

This is the workaround for my problem. You can try.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).